# Remove an ICC profile from a PDF with ABCpdf

Tags: colors, abcpdf, color-profile, color-management

We have a small utility program that removes ICC profile, and I'm trying to optimize it.

The current program uses roughly this method to remove an ICC profile:

```
foreach (var item in doc.ObjectSoup)
{
    if (item != null && doc.GetInfo(item.ID, "/ColorSpace*[0]*:Name").Equals("ICCBased", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        int profileId = doc.GetInfoInt(item.ID, "/ColorSpace*[1]:Ref"); // note the [1]: why is it there?
        if (profileId != 0)
        {
            doc.GetInfo(profileId, "Decompress");
            string profileData = doc.GetInfo(profileId, "Stream");

            // this outputs the ICC profile raw data, with the profile's name somewhere up top
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ICC profile for object ID {0}: {1}", item.ID, profileData)); 

            doc.SetInfo(profileId, "Stream", string.Empty);
            doc.GetInfo(profileId, "Compress");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to optimize it, to be able to remove only some profiles (depending on the names), or only RGB profiles for instance (and keep CMYK ones). So I wanted to use actual objects :

```
foreach (var item in doc.ObjectSoup)
{
    if (doc.GetInfo(item.ID, "Type") == "jpeg") // only work on PixMaps
    {
        PixMap pm = (PixMap)item;
        if (pm.ColorSpaceType == ColorSpaceType.ICCBased)
        {
            // pm.ColorSpace.IccProfile is always null so I can't really set it to null or Recolor() it because it would change noting
            // Also, there should already be an ICC profile (ColorSpaceType = ICCBased) but ColorSpace.IccProfile creates one (which is by design if there is none)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ICC profile for object ID {0}: {1}", item.ID, pm.ColorSpace.IccProfile));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample program that showcases the problem : https://github.com/tbroust-trepia/abcpdf8-icc-profiles

Am I doing something wrong ? Is there something weird going on with the provided images ?

I'm using ABCPdf 8.

Thanks for your help.